# sylius cart-bundle - FattalErrorException : ItemResolver::resolve() must be compatible with

Tags: php, class, symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I've installed sylius cart-bundle in my symfony 2 application.

When I try to had a product in the cart I have the following exception:

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of Lyckee\StoreBundle\Cart\ItemResolver::resolve() must be compatible with Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Resolver\ItemResolverInterface::resolve(Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartItemInterface $item, $data) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/src/Lyckee/StoreBundle/Cart/ItemResolver.php line 13

I found somebody having the same problem than me here: [Sylius CartBundle Symfony2](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f68/sylius-cartbundle-symfony2-1098500/)

He solves it with a problem in the service.yml file, but it's not working for me.

My CartItem class:

```
namespace Lyckee\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartItem as BaseCartItem;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="lyckee_cart_item_1")
 */
class CartItem extends BaseCartItem
{
    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lyckee\StoreBundle\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false))
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \Lyckee\StoreBundle\Entity\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \Lyckee\StoreBundle\Entity\Product $product
     * @return CartItem
     */

    public function setProduct(\Lyckee\StoreBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }}
```

My Item Resolver

```
namespace Lyckee\StoreBundle\Cart;

use Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartItemInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Resolver\ItemResolverInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Resolver\ItemResolvingException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ItemResolver implements ItemResolverInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function resolve(CartItemInterface $item, Request $request)
    {
        //$productId = $request->query->get('productId');

        // If no product id given, or product not found, we throw exception with nice message.
        if (!$productId || !$product = $this->getProductRepository()->find($productId)) {
            throw new ItemResolvingException('Requested product was not found');
        }

        // Assign the product to the item and define the unit price.
        $item->setProduct($product);
        $item->setUnitPrice($product->getPrix());

        // Everything went fine, return the item.
        return $item;
    }

    private function getProductRepository()
    {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository('LyckeeStoreBundle:Product');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you got this error because of when you call resolve method

```
 public function resolve(CartItemInterface $item, Request $request)
```

at that time you have to pass first parameter `$item` which has to be instace of CartItem class.

Please checkout the documentation for more detail regarding Cart Provider & Resolver.

http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/services.html

Answer (score 0):

The doc need to be updated, you just need to remove "Request" :

```
public function resolve(CartItemInterface $item, $request)
```